# Regular expression '<>' validation

Tags: regex

I'm currently working on building a regular expression that will accept URL's and hostnames.

So the following should be accepted:

```
google
google.com
www.google.com
http://google.com
http://www.google.com
```

However what should not be accepted is:

```
<xml> <html>
```

The expression I've got so far is:

```
([a-zA-Z0-9])|((http(s)?://)?([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+(/[\w- ;,./?%&=]*)?)
```

However this part of the expression: `([a-zA-Z0-9])`
matches on `<xml>` and `<html>`

Anyone any suggestions as to what I'm missing here?

Comment: What language are you using? Most language will have built in URL validation features, so you may not need to build this yourself.

Comment: @Fiona do you mean the literal strings `<xml>` and `<html>`, or do you mean html and xml tags?

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html?

Comment: **This might not be a job for regexes, but for existing tools in your language of choice.**  Regexes are not a magic wand you wave at every problem that happens to involve strings. You probably want to use existing code that has already been written, tested, and debugged.

In PHP, use the [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function.


Perl: [`URI` module](http://search.cpan.org/dist/URI/).

Ruby: [`URI` module](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html).

.NET: ['Uri' class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txt7706a.aspx)

Comment: I meant both.. both tags and literal strings. Thanks for your help. The solution was provided below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to add beginning (`^`) and end (`$`) anchors to your expression to ensure that only the pattern you specified is allowed:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)|((https?://)?([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+(/[-\w ;,./?%&=]*)?)$
```

Comment: And the `([a-zA-Z0-9])` part matches only one character, so once you add the ^ and $, that will also need to be corrected: `([a-zA-Z0-9]+)`

Comment: @BrianStephens Thanks, I've corrected that and cleaned up some other relatively minor points.